# Icon font generator for compass?

Tags: css, fonts, sass, compass-sass, icon-fonts

So sprite sheet generation in compass is pretty awesome; however, rasterized images can be limiting for some things. We have enough icons that now need to be in different colors and sizes that we are starting to make an icon font for them.

I was wondering if someone had made a gem for sass/compass to take svg files and output a bunch of hashed fonts similar to the sprite sheet functionality found in compass? I searched around online and couldn't find anything so perhaps it doesn't exist yet?

The next question is, is there an easy way to take SVGs and create fonts out of them? Is there some tool already out there that would be able to do something like this in an automated way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a gem for generate font icon. It is fontcustom.
The link: https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom

Example projects:

https://content.pivotal.io/blog/generate-icon-fonts-automatically-with-fontcustom
https://github.com/wardpenney/pivotal-blog-example-fontcustom

Comment: Oh you win! I guess it was a matter of time till this was made.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great tool to create icon fonts, you can add your svg files or choose from a wide collection of their fonts, you can create fonts in PUA format and utf8:

The Link to the app:
http://icomoon.io/